# In Rails 5 create many_to_many association along with saving either side of the relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

The title might not be very explanatory (I tried, sorry).

**The scenario**

I have a many-to-many relation, `Computer` and `Software` and thus a join model `ComputerSoftware`. I would like to have the ability to connect a computer with many softwares from the list of softwares currently available while I am creating a new computer. Here's some code to explain:

```rb
class Computer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :computer_softwares
  has_many :computers, through: :computer_softwares

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :softwares
end

class Software < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :computer_softwares
  has_many :softwares, through: :computer_softwares
end

class ComputerSoftware < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :software
  belongs_to :computer
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```rb
class ComputersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_computer, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
  before_action :set_softwares, only: :new

  def index
    @computers = Computer.all
  end

  def show; end

  def new; end

  def edit; end

  def create
    @computer = Computer.new(computer_params)
    # do something to save the associated softwares...
    # params.require(:computer).permit(:softwares) <= unpermitted param

    if @computer.save
      redirect_to computers_path, notice: 'Successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @computer.update(computer_params)
      redirect_to @computer, notice: 'Successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @computer.destroy
    redirect_to computers_url, notice: 'Successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private

  def set_computer
    @computer = Computer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def computer_params
    params.require(:computer).permit(:name)
  end

  def set_softwares
    @softwares = Software.all
  end
end
```

The association works fine, I tested in `rails console`, all good. But now I come to creating a form, say for `Computer`:

`app/views/computers/_form.html.erb`

```html
<%= form_with(model: computer, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= form.collection_check_boxes :softwares, @softwares, :id, :name, include_hidden: false do |field| %>
    <%= field.check_box %>
    <%= field.text %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have tried a few variations of this, but invariably I get some error in the view because of `softwares`, or the param is not permitted in the controller, even with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :softwares` is set in the `Computer` model.

In desperation, I opted to try to have the checkboxes not part of the `computer` at all, and create the join through association in the controller alone. This worked for `new`, but then of course broke down for `edit`. Any help greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1** (at the request of jvillian)

The strong params I tried look like this:

```rb
def computer_params
  required_params.permit(computer_softwares_attributes: [:software_id])
end

def required_params
  params.require(:computer)
end
```

but this results in the `unpermitted params` message in the server logs (and `computer_params[:computer_softwares]` is `nil` as a result). In the server logs it looks like the following:

```
Unpermitted parameters: :name, :computer_softwares
<ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>
```

**Edit 2**

Not sure why it didn't occur to me earlier - but remove the strong requirement and just doing `params[:computer][:softwares]` has actually worked fine. The only question that remains really is how I can achieve the same result using strong parameters, as otherwise it would be vulnerable.

Comment: Since you're having an `unpermitted_param` error (according to the notes in your controller code), it would likely help if you show your params as submitted to your controller.

Comment: @jvillian done now in Edit 1. I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I meant it would likely help if you show your params as submitted to your controller *from your server logs* (where you're seeing the `unpermitted_params` message). What, BTW, is `required_params`?

Comment: Sorry, I've been chopping and changing it so much, I forgot that I had abstracted `params.require(:computer)` to a separate method. Updated it now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're *still* not showing the `Parameters` as submitted to your controller. It should be the third line in your server log after `Started...` and `Processing by...`

Comment: sorry for not replying sooner. I actually found that this is a duplicate of another question (it took quite some time to find), so I will mark it as such, thanks for your help @jvillian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to permit those nested attributes inside `computer_params`:

```
def computer_params
  params.require(:computer).permit(:name, software: [:something, :something_else])
end
```

Whatever fields you want to permit for the nested software model need to go inside that `software` key